# Python module get top scope variables

Tags: python-3.x

Hey, in my python modules (written in python) I want to be able to access the variables from the top level scope, that is, the file that is calling the modules. How would I go about doing this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the way to do this is to provide some API to your plugins (e.g. a module that they import) to provide controlled access to the information they need.

If this information may vary by context, and passing in different arguments to a plugin initialisation function isn't appropriate, then an information API that uses `threading.local` under the covers may be of value.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way that will work in all environments, so a precise answer might depend on how you are running your top-level Python code.  The best thing to do is to put the variables into an object and pass the object to the functions that need it.

Comment: The thing is that I'm basically using ____import____ to dynamically import plugins for my IRC bot. The problem is that it gets difficult to access my user list and such...

Comment: Can't part of your plugin API be a call for you to pass the plugin its context?